# socket server responding multiple requests simultaneously from a client socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, queue

I am building a socket server with Python.

This server

1. receives data from client
2. does something here (approximately it takes about 10 sec in maximum depending on input data)
3. sends back data after some works done above

---

This system works fine unless client doesn't send data simultaneously in a row. For example, say server takes 5 seconds to process data and client sends data every 10 seconds. The problem, however, is that client send multiple requests at a time, thus causing a delay. Currently, client cannot send data to server unless server is ready to receive data which means that server is not doing any work. Below are what I want to build.

- a) build a queue at socket server whose main task is to make a queue of input data so that client can send data to server even when server is busy
- b) make a thread(here, I'm bit confused with concurrency and parallelism. Work in socket focused on computation rather than system call) at socket server so that server can do work 'simultaneously'.
- c) send back data to client socket

---

My questions are as follows.

1. Is it Queue that I need to use in order to achieve a) ?
2. Is it thread or something else that I need to use in order to achieve b)?

Thanks in advance

Best

Gee

Comment: You might find it easier to use one of the many existing python server frameworks.

Comment: thx @pvg I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I just saw your other comment that this is about a _single_ client, this which further simplifies this. If you're compute-bound and are looking for actual parallelism, chances are you're going to want something like multiprocessing. It's not entirely clear from what you've written so far what you're trying to accomplish but it's almost certain you don't need to reinvent it from scratch.

Comment: @pvg I've built multi-threaded socket server and was successful in reducing total computation speed. The next step would be to apply multiprocessing to further reduce the time spent during computation. Thx for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah something like this could work.

First, you'll need a thread to receive and send data. If you have limited amount of clients, you can create a thread per client, but it's not an option for a more or less robust system. In order to be able to serve multiple clients in a single thread, the sockets should be *nonblocking*. Otherwise one long transmission would block other transmissions. Nonblocking code has more sophisticated structure that uses `select`, so I would advice to spend some time reading about it.

Then you'll need a thread to do the math. Or several threads/processes if "the math" is taking long to execute.

Last but not least, these socket threads and a "math" thread should use two queues to exchange data. Simple `lists`'s are enough, but make sure they are *synchronized*. Guard them with mutexes, or locks. This is another vast topic that is worth reading about.

Comment: Thx @Vovanrock2002.
In my case, I don't have multiple clients. I only have one client. That 'single' client sends multiple request in near real-time. That being said, is your comment still valid?

Comment: @GeeYeolNahm yes, in this case one IO thread and one or several execution threads would be fine.

Comment: Thx @Vovanrock2002. I could successfully build a socket server with your help!